# my discord bot just repeats my first message

Tags: python, discord

I'm configuring a bot to facilitate the company's service, in which we use colors to define priority. But the bot is only copying the first word, not the whole sentence. I've tried a few things, but it's easier to ask someone you already know for help.

down here is the red color code. Here is an example print

https://prnt.sc/hiMr2f7l5CYO

````
@client.command(name="v")
async def v (context, message):
        await context.message.channel.send("```diff\n-" + message + "\n```")
        await context.message.delete()
````

I configured this line of code to copy the entire sentence, but it only repeats the first sentence. ❤

Comment: What have you tried to fix the issue? For example, a very logical first debugging step would be to print `message` to the console to see what the function is getting as its input

Comment: thank you very much, the bot is working the way i wanted it to. With your help I'm evolving ❤.
Result: https://prnt.sc/1wGoGPnBTq5T